# REGEXMATCH across multiple worksheets in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to pull the "Meals" data from across multiple worksheets.  The following produces the #ERROR message instead.

```
=sum(filter('jan20':'aug30'!E10:E108, regexmatch('jan20':'aug30'!I10:I108, "Meals")))
```

---

```
1/3/2020    DEBIT   HILTONS FOOD SER    -$14.14             Expense: Meals
1/21/2020   DEBIT   LA MADELEINE SHO    -$17.12             Expense: Meals
1/21/2020   DEBIT   LA MADELEINE SHO    -$5.95              Expense: Meals
1/31/2020   DEBIT   MECHES SUPERMARK    -$8.30
```

Comment: Hey, I think this part of the formula is wrong : `'jan20':'aug30'!xx:xx`  are you trying to pull data from several worksheets (jan, feb, mar, etc.. aug) ?

Comment: Yes, trying to pull from several worksheets as you've indicated. What should I correct in the formula?

Comment: Unfortunately, `=Filter` 's condition is restricted to a single column. However you can try a query. Can you share some sample data ?

Comment: Sure, but the sample I paste appears jumbled up, & this doesn't accept a paste from clipboard.  What shld I do?  Thx!

Comment: maybe a dummy sheet ?